# How Do I add custom fonts to my react native project when it says "link" is not a command and npx react-native-asset is not doing anything

Tags: node.js, react-native, fonts

My react-native-cli version is `2.0.1` and my react-native version is`0.72.6`. I've been trying to add the Monospace font to my project. I already made an asset folder with a font folder inside with the Monospace.ttf files inside already in the root directory of the project. I also made a
react-native.config.js file and inside I have this:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        android:{},
        ios:{},
    },
    assets:['./assets/fonts/'],
}
```

When I try to use `react-native link` it says that link is not recognized as a command. When I try to use `npx react-native-asset` It doesn't do anything and just sends me to the next line. I also tried installing the react-native-asset globally and it did install but the `npx react-native-asset` did not work after.

Here is what I tried to put:

```
titleText: {
            position: 'relative',
            bottom: 200,
            fontSize: 55,
            fontFamily: 'Monospace',
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android react-native, you have to do further steps to make it works.

1. Copy static font files into /android/app/src/main/res/font
2. Rename the font file names to make all lowercases.
3. Create {{font name}}.xml
   for example: oswald.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="200" android:font="@font/oswald_extralight" />
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="300" android:font="@font/oswald_light" />
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/oswald_regular" />
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="500" android:font="@font/oswald_medium" />
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="600" android:font="@font/oswald_semibold" />
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="700" android:font="@font/oswald_bold" />
</font-family>
```

4. Add follow code into MainApplication.Java

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // ...
    ReactFontManager.getInstance().addCustomFont(this, "Oswald", R.font.oswald);
}
```